# I have added java mysql connector to my project but my project still cannot use it

Tags: java, mysql

this is my class, it was used to get connection

```
// Database credentials
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pornism";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "1";
static final String HOST_NAME = "localhost";
static final String DB_NAME = "pornism";

// Connection and Statement of current session

public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST_NAME + ":3306/" + DB_NAME;
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,USER,PASS);
        System.out.println("Successfull!!");
        return conn;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is what it showed when i was trying get connection

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crewup
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at data.Database.getConnection(Database.java:22)
at prototype.LoginMethod.doPost(LoginMethod.java:45)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:609)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And I have added mysql connector to my project:
[Eclipse build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzJ3K.png)

Can anyone tell me why does it not working? I have tryed to find.

Comment: I think you haven't put the connector in the directory of the project that's why it is not able to find the connector.

Comment: I think, You are using wrong version of driver. please download correct version from this site. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `Class.forName`.

Try the below snippet.

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  try {
      Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);  // Add this line.
      String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST_NAME + ":3306/" + DB_NAME;
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,USER,PASS);
      System.out.println("Successfull!!");
      return conn;
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tryed but not working. Everything is so weird now. I also tryed moving that code to a new maven project which already added mysql-connector-java dependency and it worked normally but when running in this project, it still caused that error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import MySQL JDBC driver into your project's library?

Comment: Please don't ask for clarifications about the question as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysql507jar.htm

I tested your code.
download JDBC driver jar file and then import it to your project. Test again.

ps : Từ group qua đây : ))

Answer (score 0):

You must called `Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER)` first.